# Can't get HttpServletRequest from Spring with credentials attached

Tags: java, spring, servlets, httprequest

I'm trying to get the request object from Spring in a web application, however whatever approach I take the username (/credentials) piece is always missing.

I've used the @Autowired and

```
HttpServletRequest curRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

approaches, but the request looks like its had all credential information removed by Spring.

How do I get these back?  I need a full request object to create a credentials object needed by another library.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Comment: <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject `HttpServletRequest` into your controller.
If you need to get the user name, you can inject `java.security.Principal` as well.

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String path(Principal principal, HttpServletRequest request) {
   // do ur thing
   // return username
   principal.getName();
   return "path";
}
```

Comment: Hi,  I need a request object to instantiate Modeshape ServletCredentials(req), but because all the credentials data has been removed by Spring the ServletCredentials instance is basically useless.  How do I get back to the _original_ request before Spring removed the useful bits?   Thanks

Comment: OK I've thought of another way to do this - thanks anyway.